# How to get my albums from Flickr using php or laravel

Tags: flickr

How can i display all the Flickr photos into my website? I have tried to find out but there is no any API available which can be use full in latest version of php and laravel.
Anybody have solution for how to display my album of Flickr on my website?

Answer (score 0):

A quick search on packagist gave me the following result:

https://packagist.org/packages/jeroen-g/flickr

It provides you with an larval implementation.

Comment: Thank you for response. I have tried this one also but it is not working. In which laravel version you have used?

Comment: I haven't used it myself. I don't see why it shouldn't work  make sure you follow the github readme and set the API key in your `.env` file. What error are you getting. (Suggest you edit the question with what you already tried and what error you are getting)

Comment: There is version issue and this all are not working in latest version of laravel. i have already mentioned that i have tried to find out and there is few of apis like this are available but this all are not working in latest version of laravel.

Comment: @daxter include the exact error (screenshot, copy of text) and add it to your question (edit the question). Without an exact error it is very hard to figure out why it is not working.

Comment: You are right thank you for response. I really appreciating this and i have tried many of this apis and this all errors are based on command line and by providing this errors with screenshot with all tries i don't think it will be usefull for anyone to understand.

Comment: if nothing works try using their api documentation to perform your own requests? https://www.flickr.com/services/api/

Comment: Yes good one. Thanks for giving this link i have already tried this one there is no any error or result coming in response.

Comment: It has been over a year but actually this package works:

https://packagist.org/packages/jeroen-g/flickr

Just be sure to run the command `php artisan config:clear` after adding your keys in `.env` file